# Running into encoding problems when exporting a table to a YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, yaml

I'm getting the following error when I export a table to a yaml file:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

This is the code that generate the error:

```
  File.open("#{Rails.root}/lib/users.yml", 'w') do |file|
    users = User.all
    YAML::dump(users, file)
  end
```

I've tried doing this on the content attributes of all User models:

```
about_me.force_encoding("utf-8")
save
```

...to no avail, apparently. Was I forcing the encoding correctly? Is there another way to get around this problem? I don't mind getting rid of non-utf8 characters; how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This fixed this error for me:

```
myString.unpack('U*').pack('U*')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/astro/utf8cleaner for cleaning non-utf8 chars.
You you can try str.encode('utf-8', :invalid => :replace, :replace => ''), which for some reason didn't work for me. Another thing that you can try is writing the file in ASCII-8BIT, like in File.open('file.yml', 'w:ASCII-8BIT')

Comment: Cool. Ended up dumping to JSON instead of YAML, which fixed the problem. Will try this if I have to use YAML again.